# Implicit declaration of function is invalid error for Perl module install on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, perl, cpan

I'm trying to install the `Text::Unaccent` module for Perl (5.30.3) using `cpan` (1.64) on macOS Monterey 12.4 but I'm getting 12 warnings and 1 error:

```
Unaccent.xs:109:10: error: implicit declaration of function 'unac_debug_callback' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            unac_debug_callback(in, unac_debug_print, NULL);
```

My understanding is that this is some kind of missing header file? I've installed a few other Perl modules successfully, this is the first problem I've come across. I've installed xcode and the command line tools are installed and up to date.

An example of the warnings is:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/perl.h:545:21: note: expanded from macro 'STMT_END'
#   define STMT_END     )
```

This is not a custom Perl build, its the default installation. Is there other package/library that I need to install to get passed this?

> macOS Monteray 12.4 (Intel)
> /usr/bin/cpan version 1.64 calling Getopt::Std::getopts (version 1.12 [paranoid]),
> running under Perl version 5.30.3.
> xcode-select version 2395

Comment: [Bug report filed in 2018](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=124815). The module itself hasn't been updated since 2004, so it's not likely this bit rot is going to be fixed unless someone takes over the package from the long-gone owner.

Comment: @Shawn thanks that fix didn't work for me and I eventually gave up trying to fix it by hacking on the source. In the end I installed Text::Unaccent::PurePerl. Its got the same API and some fixes/improvements I believe.